# Bug in animation when loading List asynchronously

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I'm trying to make two `List` components: one of them is static and small, the second is incredibly large and dynamic. In the first `List` I store food categories: Alcoholic products, Soups, Cereals, etc. In the second `List`, the word is searched directly from the database - it can be anything: a dish or a category of dishes. Below is the code - it displays the start page. Initially, the first static and small `List` is located on it, as well as the Search component (`Navigationview.seacrhable()`). When you type a word into the search bar, the first `List` disappears and the second one appears. At the moment, both sheets are loaded asynchronously. This is necessary because the second sheet is really big (thousands of rows). This is where my problem begins. Sometimes, when you type a word into the search bar, a copy of this sheet appears on top of it, as shown in the image. It only happens for a fraction of a second, but it's still noticeable. The problem is most likely due to asynchronous loading, before I added it, the `List` was loading super slowly, but without such bugs.

**My minimal reproducible example:**

***ContentView.sfiwt***

Main List, displaying the food categories available for selection.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State public var addScreen: Bool = true
    @State private var searchByWordView: Bool = true
    @State private var searchByWordCategoryView: Bool = true
    @State public var gram: String = ""
    @State private var selectedFood: String = ""
    @State private var selectedFoodCategoryItem: String = ""
    @State private var selectedFoodTemp: String = ""
    @State private var selectedFoodCategoryTemp: String = ""
    @State private var FoodCList: [FoodCategory] = []
    @State private var FoodList: [FoodItemByName] = []
    @State var foodItems: [String] = []
    @MainActor
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    if !searchByWordView {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(FoodList, id:\.self){i in
                                Button(action: {
                                    selectedFoodTemp = i.name
                                    addScreen.toggle()
                                }){Text("\(i.name)")}.foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(FoodCList, id:\.self){i in
                                NavigationLink(destination: GetFoodCategoryItemsView(category: "\(i.name)")) {
                                    Text("\(i.name)")
                                }.foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .task{
                    FoodCList = await FillFoodCategoryList()
                }
                if !addScreen {
                    addSreenView(addScreen: $addScreen, gram: $gram, selectedFood: $selectedFoodTemp, foodItems: $foodItems)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add the dish")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .searchable(
            text: $selectedFood,
            placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
            prompt:  "Search by word"
        )
        .onChange(of: selectedFood, perform: {i in
            if i.isEmpty {
                searchByWordView = true
            } else {
                searchByWordView = false
                Task {
                    FoodList = await GetFoodItemsByName(_name: selectedFood)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    func GetFoodCategoryItemsView(category: String) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                if !searchByWordCategoryView {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(GetFoodCategoryItems(_category: category).filter{$0.name.contains(selectedFoodCategoryItem)}, id:\.self){i in
                            Button(action: {
                                selectedFoodCategoryTemp = i.name
                                addScreen.toggle()
                            }){Text("\(i.name)")}
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(GetFoodCategoryItems(_category: category), id:\.self){i in
                            Button(action: {
                                selectedFoodCategoryTemp = i.name
                                addScreen.toggle()
                            }){Text("\(i.name)")}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if !addScreen {
                addSreenView(addScreen: $addScreen, gram: $gram, selectedFood: $selectedFoodCategoryTemp, foodItems: $foodItems)
            }
        }
        .searchable(
            text: $selectedFoodCategoryItem,
            placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
            prompt: "Search by word"
        )
        .onChange(of: selectedFoodCategoryItem, perform: {i in
            if i.isEmpty {
                searchByWordCategoryView = true
            } else {
                searchByWordCategoryView = false
            }
        })
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationTitle(category)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

***AddSreenView.swift***

Modal window of entering grams of food consumed.

```
import SwiftUI

struct addSreenView: View {
    @Binding var addScreen: Bool
    @Binding var gram: String
    @Binding var selectedFood: String
    @Binding var foodItems: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(.black)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onTapGesture{withAnimation(.linear){addScreen.toggle()}}
            VStack(spacing:0){
                Text("Add a dish/meal")
                    .padding()
                Divider()
                VStack(){
                    TextField("Weight, in gram", text: $gram)
                        .padding(.leading, 16)
                        .padding(.trailing, 16)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.leading, 16)
                        .padding(.trailing, 16)
                }.padding()
                Divider()
                HStack(){
                    Button(action: {
                        foodItems.append("\(selectedFood), \(gram) g.")
                        gram = ""
                        selectedFood = ""
                        addScreen.toggle()
                    }){
                        Text("Save")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    Divider()
                    Button(action: {
                        gram = ""
                        selectedFood = ""
                        addScreen.toggle()
                    }){
                        Text("Cancel")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }.frame(height: 50)
            }
            .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(10))
            .frame(maxWidth: 350)
        }
    }
}
```

***GetFunction.swift***

This file simulates my real SQLite database queries.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// Fill start pade List (all categories of dishes)
struct FoodCategory: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
}

func FillFoodCategoryList() async -> [FoodCategory] {
    let catList: [FoodCategory] = [FoodCategory(name: "Alcohol"),FoodCategory(name: "Soups"),FoodCategory(name: "Cereals"),FoodCategory(name: "Fish"),FoodCategory(name: "Meat")]
    return catList
}

// Search by word List
struct FoodItemByName: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
}

func GetFoodItemsByName(_name: String) async -> [FoodItemByName] {
    var foodItemsByName: [FoodItemByName] = []
    let items: [String] = ["Light beer with 11% dry matter in the original wort","Light beer with 20% of dry matter in the original wort","Dark beer with 13% dry matter content in the original wort","Dark beer, with a proportion of dry substances in the initial wort of 20%","Dry white and red wines (including champagne)","Semi-dry white and red wines (including champagne)","Semi-sweet white and red wines (including champagne)","Sweet white and red wines (including champagne)","Strong wines","Semi-dessert wines","Dessert wines","Liqueur wines","Slivyanka liqueur","Cherry liqueur","Ordinary cognac - Three stars","Vodka"]
    let filteredItems = items.filter{ $0.contains("\(_name)") }
    for i in filteredItems {
        foodItemsByName.append(FoodItemByName(name: i))
    }
    return foodItemsByName
}

// List appears when you click on Alcohole in start page (by analogy with other categories of dishes)
struct FoodCategoryItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
}

func GetFoodCategoryItems(_category: String) -> [FoodCategoryItem] {
    var foodCategoryItems: [FoodCategoryItem] = []
    let _alcohole: [String] = ["Light beer with 11% dry matter in the original wort","Light beer with 20% of dry matter in the original wort","Dark beer with 13% dry matter content in the original wort","Dark beer, with a proportion of dry substances in the initial wort of 20%","Dry white and red wines (including champagne)","Semi-dry white and red wines (including champagne)","Semi-sweet white and red wines (including champagne)","Sweet white and red wines (including champagne)","Strong wines","Semi-dessert wines","Dessert wines","Liqueur wines","Slivyanka liqueur","Cherry liqueur","Ordinary cognac - Three stars","Vodka"]
    let _soup: [String] = ["Chicken soup","French onion soup","Tomato soup","Chicken Dumpling Soup","Beef Stew","Cream of Potato","Lobster Bisque","Chili Con Carne","Clam Chowder","Cream Of Cheddar Broccoli"]
    let _cereals: [String] = ["Cinnamon Toast Crunch","Frosted Flakes","Honey Nut Cheerios","Lucky Charms","Froot Loops","Fruity Pebbles","Cap'n Crunch","Cap'n Crunch's Crunch Berries","Cocoa Puffs","Reese's Puffs"]
    let _fish: [String] = ["Salmon","Tuna","Cod","Rainbow Trout","Halibut","Red Snapper","Flounder","Bass","Mahi-Mahi","Catfish"]
    let _meat: [String] = ["Beef","Chicken (Food)","Lamb","Pork","Duck","Turkey","Venison","Buffalo","American Bison"]
    if _category == "Alcohol"{
        for i in _alcohole{foodCategoryItems.append(FoodCategoryItem(name: i))}
    } else if _category == "Soups" {
        for i in _soup{foodCategoryItems.append(FoodCategoryItem(name: i))}
    } else if _category == "Cereals" {
        for i in _cereals{foodCategoryItems.append(FoodCategoryItem(name: i))}
    } else if _category == "Fish" {
        for i in _fish{foodCategoryItems.append(FoodCategoryItem(name: i))}
    } else {
        for i in _meat{foodCategoryItems.append(FoodCategoryItem(name: i))}
    }
    return foodCategoryItems
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have a [mre] to play with. What you have won't compile because there are too many missing types. I do notice a couple of things with your hierarchy in general that *may* be messing with SwiftUI's ability to efficiently diff the views. Have you watched the Demystifying SwiftUI session from the 2021 WWDC?

Comment: @jnpdx , good morning, I'm so sorry that I did not see your comment earlier, I'll make a working sample as soon as possible and attach a link to GitHub with the project.

Comment: @jnpdx, I have translated the Alcoholic Beverages section in the database into English, I think now there is everything to experiment with the problem.

Comment: Rather than making people download the whole project from a different source, it would be ideal to include a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx, I hope I got the idea right. The presented code has everything to make it run. The GetFunction.swift file simulates my SQLite database queries. The remaining files fully correspond to those in the project.

Comment: @jnpdx, I looked at "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC2021, it greatly expanded my understanding of working with views, but, unfortunately, I could not independently find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I think I've managed to localize the problem. After watching SwiftUI Demystifying, I wondered which specific ids I use in ForeEach. I decided to change them to \.name and the problem began to appear many times less often. Maybe this is part of the solution to the problem? Apple recommends using super stable IDs in such lists, for example, taken from a database. I'll try to do that too.

Comment: I think instead of `\.name` you should use `\.id` -- that's what an id is for. In fact, you can omit that parameter completely and SwiftUI will know to use the`.id` parameter. This next thing won't affect performance at all, but you also may want to consider following the Swift naming conventions -- types get a capital letter, variables and properties start with lowercase. It'll make it easier for others to read your code. Both of those things being said, I haven't figured out a perfect solution to your issue yet.

Comment: If you move `searchByWordView = false` to *after* `FoodList` gets set (within the `Task`) does it solve the issue? I can't tell for sure since the issue happens extremely sporadically on my machine.

Comment: Like this? No, it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Task {
                    FoodList = await GetFoodItemsByName(_name: selectedFood)
                    searchByWordView = false
                }

Comment: If from the main screen you go to alcoholic beverages and try to use the search bar there - the problem should appear, here I met it most often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using `id` for the IDs, as mentioned in the comments, you can do some refactoring to get SwiftUI to not re-render as much of the view hierarchy and instead reuse components. For example, you have an `if` condition and in each you have separate `Section`, `ForEach`, etc components. Instead, you could render the content of the `ForEach` based on the state of the search:

```
func categoryItems(category: String) -> [FoodCategoryItem] {
    if !searchByWordCategoryView {
        return GetFoodCategoryItems(_category: category).filter{$0.name.contains(selectedFoodCategoryItem)}
    } else {
        return GetFoodCategoryItems(_category: category)
    }
}

func GetFoodCategoryItemsView(category: String) -> some View {
    ZStack {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(categoryItems(category: category)){i in
                    Button(action: {
                        selectedFoodCategoryTemp = i.name
                        addScreen.toggle()
                    }){Text("\(i.name)")}
                }
            }
            if !addScreen {
                addSreenView(addScreen: $addScreen, gram: $gram, selectedFood: $selectedFoodCategoryTemp, foodItems: $foodItems)
            }
        }
    }
    .searchable(
        text: $selectedFoodCategoryItem,
        placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
        prompt: "Search by word"
    )
    .onChange(of: selectedFoodCategoryItem, perform: {i in
        if i.isEmpty {
            searchByWordCategoryView = true
        } else {
            searchByWordCategoryView = false
        }
    })
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .navigationTitle(category)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .interactiveDismissDisabled()
}
```

Comment: I got the idea. But I have the following question. If you go back to the first part of the code, you will notice that there are different elements inside Foreach: Button and Navigation Link. I can do this: ForEach(search By Word View ? FoodList:Foodslist), but how can I change the Button to Navigation Link depending on the value of searchByWordView?

Comment: You’d have to provide a different foreach for each state in that case.